# Is there a way to add the "Part" section to the IEEE Transactions on Magnetics document class?

Tags: sectioning, ieeetran

I am using the IEEE Transactions on Magnetics document class in LYX and am having difficulties with the "Part" section. All other sectioning types (section, subsection, paragraph, etc.) work fine, but when I add a "Part" section and try to view I get the following message:

> `\part`
>
> ```
>      {Digital Control}
> ```
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
>      of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
>      misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx`), type `I` and the correct
>      spelling (e.g., `I\hbox`). Otherwise just continue,
>      and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Is there something that I can add to my preamble to fix this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I can't find any mention of the `\part` command in the documentation to the IEEEtrans class. So probably it is not implemented for it (as it is the case for `\chapter`)

Comment: I was afraid of that. It's weird that 'Part' appears in the sectioning drop-down menu, but I can't use it. Is there any way to easily implement it? I really like the IEEE format for the type of document I am writing. I would just like to be able to differentiate between two clearly separate parts and have it show in the TOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `IEEEtran` class has no `\part` command *although* is is based on the `article` class which does.

A possible fix would be to re-include the definitions of the `article.cls` class file into your document, like:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\makeatletter
\newcounter {part}
\renewcommand \thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
\newcommand\part{%
   \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
   \par
   \addvspace{4ex}%
   \@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\@part\@spart}
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \Large\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par\nobreak
     \fi
     \huge \bfseries #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \huge \bfseries #1\par}%
     \nobreak
     \vskip 3ex
     \@afterheading}
\newcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
       \if@compatibility
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \filetter}                                                                                                                                                                    
\makeatother                                                                                                                                                                    
\renewcommand\partname{Part}                                                                                                                                                    

\usepackage{lipsum}                                                                                                                                                             
\title{A way to use the 'Part' command in Latex}                                                                                                                                
\author{John Doe}                                                                                                                                                               
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                
\maketitle                                                                                                                                                                      
\begin{abstract}                                                                                                                                                                
\lipsum[1]                                                                                                                                                                      
\end{abstract}                                                                                                                                                                  
\part{First Part of the Article}                                                                                                                                                
Some text right after the part. Maybe some summary or so. \lipsum[1]                                                                                                            

See that there was no indentation after the part, which just comes after the                                                                                                    
first paragraph of written words.                                                                                                                                               
\section{First section}                                                                                                                                                         
\lipsum                                                                                                                                                                         
\section{Second section}                                                                                                                                                        
\lipsum                                                                                                                                                                         
\part{Second Part of the Article}                                                                                                                                               
This part only has a single section.                                                                                                                                            
\section{Last section}                                                                                                                                                          
\lipsum                                                                                                                                                                         
\end{document}
```

As I've just c&p'ed the corresponding parts of the code from `article.cls`, there  can still be possible bugs (I actually had to change one or to `\newcommand` into `\renewcommand` to get this working, and also to include the code between `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`, where I've probably included more than necessary).

Maybe it would be better to define your own article class instead, and include all the features you like from the `IEEEtran.cls` file.

Comment: Damn! Thanks for that! I guess I probably would be better off creating a custom class, I was just hoping to be able to avoid that. Oh well, such is the way of things. I really appreciate your help with this. It'll make creating a custom class much easier!

Comment: Best ask for help on how to implement the features for the custom class on this site step-by-step, as I am not 100% sure if everything in the code above is 100% kosher.